# How do I add a classic ASP.NET Web Forms with virtual directory to a container in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-service-fabric

I want to migrate a classic ASP.NET Web Forms that has virtual directories into a container for inclusion as a service in Service Fabric.

Currently, I add the virtual directories in IIS and map to physical drive locations on my local system. If I add these to a container, how will IIS know to map them as virtual directory instead of just another folder?

The process I am looking to achieve is this

1. Set up a container with IIS
2. Copy my current deployment into the wwwroot folder in IIS ( In the container )
3. Create virtual directory under the deployed site and copy some files into it
4. All these as part of the container creation process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/) to see how to run IIS inside a Windows Container on Service Fabric. 
The trick is to run the entire application along with IIS inside a container, not just IIS by itself. This way, nothing runs 'locally' on the host node and deployment is much simpler.

More info about how to create the docker file and optionally create a new website by using PowerShell [here](https://www.ntweekly.com/2018/04/05/create-iis-website-dockerfile/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc) and [here](https://blog.sixeyed.com/1-2-3-iis-running-in-nano-server-in-docker-on-windows-server-2016/).
How to create a virtual dir using PowerShell `New-WebVirtualDirectory` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/new-webvirtualdirectory?view=winserver2012-ps).

Comment: Thanks for the links . Gave me insights into some of my questions . What about creating virtual directories and pointing them to paths where the files are on the container. Sorry I am just trying to learn about docker and containers. Thanks again

Comment: I added another link to the answer

Comment: Thanks . I think that last link should do it for me.